# Make a percentage of turtles die

Tags: netlogo

Every click I want a specific percentage of turtles to die (i.e. 50%). Currently I am using the code:

```
if random 100 < 50 [die]
```

Whilst this works, it is not consistent, eventually, by pure chance, all the turtles will die using this method.

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`ask n-of (count turtles / 2) turtles [ die ]` will kill exactly 50% of the turtles. (If the number of turtles is odd, the extra turtle is spared.)